# how to change a file after running the release plugin

Tags: maven, release, profile

I want to add the new pom version after running mvn release plugin to a file and then commit the changes. 
I don't want to add a new pom. 
also we thought about adding a new profile but then it will run the build part of the build and we don't want that to happened. 
what can we do?

Comment: You could create an ant task which could do that, check: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/

Comment: You could use the  [GMavenPlus plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVENPLUS/Home) or [create your own Maven plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/index.html), too.